# How to view images using plt.imshow() without getting "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 49152 into shape (128,128)"?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, reshape

I'm trying to display 9 images from my validation set along with the class that my model predicted, but I'm getting an error due to the reshape element of `plt.imshow()`. The number of pixels and channels for my images is `(128, 128, 3)` (RGB). I've tried changing the reshape size to `(128, 128, 1)` and `(128, 128, 3)` and `(1, 128, 128)` and none of those options work. How do I know what these numbers should be so that plt.imshow() works successfully? I know there are related StackOverflow question but the answers to those posts haven't helped me.

```
target_size=(128,128) # target pixel size of each image
batch_size = 20  # the number of images to load per iteration

# configure a data generator which will rescale the images and create a training
# and test split where the test set is 10% of the data
data_gen_3 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.1)

val_img = data_gen_3.flow_from_directory(data_path, 
                                               subset='validation',
                                               color_mode='rgb',
                                               target_size=target_size,
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               class_mode='categorical')

# get a sample of 20 (batch_size) validation images
sample_imgs_val, sample_labels_val = next(val_img)

# predict the class for the sample val images using the final model called "convnet"
X_pred_class = convnet.predict(sample_imgs_val)

# get the most likely class number for the prediction for each image
predicted_classes = np.argmax(X_pred_class, axis=1)

# display 9 of the images along with the predicted class
for img in range(9):
    plt.subplot(3, 3, img + 1, frameon=False)
    plt.imshow( np.reshape(sample_imgs_val[img],(128,128)) )
    plt.title(predicted_classes[img])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib` can display color pictures, e.g., pictures with 3 channels. I don't understand why you are trying to remove the channel's dimensions.

If you want to remove the channels, that would be akin to turning it to a grayscale image. For this, I suggest you use `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image

grey_image = np.array(Image.fromarray(color_image).convert('L'))
```

You will have to change the `cmap` in `matplotlib` to see the picture in greyscale.

```
plt.imshow(grey_image, cmap='Greys')
```

If you're **not trying to turn the image into a grayscale**, you should just leave the picture as it is.

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. __If you want to say "thank you," vote and accept that person's answer__. _READ_: [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).